# SQL Query - Left Join Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables :

The first one is for receptions details and the second one is for receptions header.

```
CREATE TABLE ACH_ReceptionsDet
(
    IdReception bigint NOT NULL,
    IdProd bigint,
    QteRecue numeric(16,5),
);

CREATE TABLE ACH_ReceptionsEnt
(
    IdReception bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DateRec datetime NOT NULL,
);
```

I would like to get last IdProd, QteRecue, DateRec for each IdProd.
In other words I would like to get last reception of each products.

**EDIT :**

For now i'm able to get DateRecep and IdProd like this **(4862 results)**:

```
SELECT
  MAX(E.DateRec) AS DateRecp,
  D.IdProd
FROM ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsDet D
  LEFT JOIN ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsEnt E
    ON D.IdReception = E.IdReception
GROUP BY D.IdProd
```

I cannot add D.QteRecue in select because it is not contained in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause. I don't understand how to do that.

If i run this query **(4862 results)**:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT Idprod)
FROM ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsDet
```

But if i add E.QteRecue **(6973 results)**

```
SELECT
      MAX(E.DateRec) AS DateRecp,
      D.IdProd,
      **E.QteRecue**
    FROM ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsDet D
      LEFT JOIN ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsEnt E
        ON D.IdReception = E.IdReception
    GROUP BY D.IdProd, **E.QteRecue**
```

Comment: You would add it as a second column in the group by. Surely the examples you found that got you this far showed you this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the column to the group by should fix the issue:

```
SELECT
  MAX(E.DateRec) AS DateRecp,
  D.IdProd,
  D.QteRecue
FROM ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsDet D
  LEFT JOIN ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsEnt E
    ON D.IdReception = E.IdReception
GROUP BY D.IdProd, D.QteRecue;
```

Comment: Adding D.QteRecue in group by adding like 2000 lines

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `row_number()`:

```
SELECT de.*
FROM (SELECT DateRecp, D.IdProd, D.QteRecue,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.IdProd ORDER BY DateRecp DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsDet D LEFT JOIN
           ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsEnt E
           ON D.IdReception = E.IdReception
     ) de
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query like this

```
    SELECT temp.DateRecp,
        ,temp.IdProd
        ,R.QteRecue
FROM ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsDet R 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(E.DateRec) AS DateRecp
            ,D.IdProd  
    FROM ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsDet D
    LEFT JOIN ogasys.ACH_ReceptionsEnt E ON D.IdReception = E.IdReception
    GROUP BY D.IdProd) AS temp ON R.IdProd = temp.IdProd
```